# Probability Of a Disease

Tags: probability

If the probability of a team of people developing a disease is 0.05 then how many is it expected to get ill, if the number of the participants is 500? What is the probability that 10 people will get ill? The answer to the first question is pretty obvious and is actually 500*0.05. But I am not sure how to move with the second question.

Comment: please type the question exactly how it is written. At the moment it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this using a binomial distribution with $n = 500$ and $p = 0.05$. Thus,

\begin{align*}
P(10 \text{ get ill}) = \binom{500}{10}\cdot (0.05)^{10} \cdot (1-0.05)^{500-10} \approx .00029165
\end{align*}

Comment: Is that a formula in probabilities because it is the first time I am seeing this? Could you explain it ?

Comment: yes. it is the standard form of the binomial distribution, which you should look up.